# Linker cannot find .lib file

Tags: c++, cmake, build, box2d

I am trying to get an external library working (box2d for what it matters) and have added the include path to "C_Cpp.default.includePath" and CMake is finding it properly as it has no errors. The problem is when building it says:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'box2d.lib' [path\to\proj\build\ProjName.vcxproj]`

I have looked at the file it says this:

```xml
<AdditionalDependencies>D:\Program Files\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-graphics-d.lib;D:\Program Files\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-audio-d.lib;D:\Program Files\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-network-d.lib;box2d.lib;D:\Program Files\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-window-d.lib;D:\Program Files\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-system-d.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
```

This from what I can see is that while sfml was somehow correctly installed box2d is expected to be in PATH? I have tried adding the path to the lib in the launch.json via:

```json
"environment": [{"name": "PATH","value":"path/to/Box2D/lib;%PATH%;"}],
```

but that didn't seem to help either.

In my CMakeLists.txt I added `find_package(Box2D REQUIRED)`

If there is any other information that is missing please tell me.

Entire CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(VSGame)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS network audio graphics window system REQUIRED)
find_package(Box2D REQUIRED)

add_executable(VSGame
    main.cpp 
    ResourceManager.hpp
    Game.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(VSGame sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-network box2d)
```

box2d path: `D:\packages\Box2D`, the box2d.lib file is located under `D:\packages\Box2D\lib` and the cmake folder/files are located under `D:\packages\Box2D\lib\cmake\box2d`

Comment: Please post complete `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Where is box2d actually installed? Where exactly is the (import) lib located? Does it provide cmake configuration files? If not, it may be a good idea to add an imported target.

Comment: Updated the post with both things you requested.